# My Wikipedia-inspired Django project returns an error whenever I click an entry

Tags: python, django, server, backend, typeerror

I work with Django to create a Wikipedia-like app (course project). When I click one of my entries, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: entry() got multiple values for argument 'title'
```

Here the view I created for entries in views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def entry(request, title):
flag = util.get_entry(title)
if flag is None:
    form = SearchForm()
    content = "The page you look for does not exist :("
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {"form": form, "content": content})
else:
    form = SearchForm()
    mdcontent = util.get_entry(title)
    htmlcontent = markdowner.convert(mdcontent)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "title": title, "content": htmlcontent, "form": form
    })
```

Do you notice multiple values for title? I'm new to Django and can't figure out the problem. Your help will be appreciated.

**Traceback:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/wiki/CSS

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/workspaces/79201800/wiki/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner response = get_response(request)
File "/workspaces/79201800/wiki/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, title, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/workspaces/79201800/wiki/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /wiki/CSS
Exception Value: entry() got multiple values for argument 'title'
```

Comment: What this is saying is that the web page that made the request had a `<form>` that had multiple `<input>` tags called "title".

Comment: Can you please share the full stack trace and your `urls.py` pattern for `entry` ?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hmm.. This is weird because there is no form in entry page.

Comment: @sytech Sure. The traceback was too long to copy+paste here so I edited my post. Please find it above. And here's my url pattern for `entry`: `path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")`

Comment: Hmm. So what is happening is that Django is calling your view both with positional argument for `title` (or perhaps some other parameter erroneously passed positionally in place of where title should go) AND is also specifying a keyword argument for `title` at the same time. This might happen for a number of reasons... what might help degbug this is to change the view signature to `def entry(request, *args, **kwargs):` then `print('args:', args, 'kwargs:' kwargs, sep='\n')` as the first line -- That should let us see what values are being passed and maybe that will give us another clue.

Comment: Also is your view in a class or just a standalone function view? [This question may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714495/django-typeerror-get-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument-invoice-id).

Comment: @sytech No, not in a class. However I tried the debugging method you mentioned and `def entry(self, request):` but still threw the same error. Then I removed `title` from `def entry(request, title):` which I additionally added, so now it's just `def entry(request):`. This time it throws that error: `TypeError: entry() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'` Traceback is same. Still have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: @RumeysaGelgi That was not what I suggested. Pay close attention to my previous comment. Use variadic parameters (`*args`, `**kwargs`) !! Then you should never have that TypeError and you can continue debugging.